# Countable union of paracompact spaces is Paracompact with regularity?

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

When studying "Paracompactness", I thought that

If $X$ is regular, and $X= \bigcup  Y_n$  ($n\ge1$) where $Y_n$ is paracompact subspace of $X$,

then $X$ is paracompact.

Here is the proof.

> Suppose $\mathcal A$ be open covering of $X$. 
>   For each $n\ge1$, since $\mathcal A$ is open covering of  $Y_n$,
>
> there exists open refinement $\mathcal B_n$ of $\mathcal A$ such that is locally finite and covers $Y_n$ .
>
> Then define, $$\mathcal B= \bigcup \mathcal B_n$$
>   Obviously, $\mathcal B$ is open covering of $X$. And for any $B \in \mathcal B$,
>   $\exists  n\ge 1$   such that $B \in \mathcal B_n$
>
> So, there exists $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $B \subset A$ , because $\mathcal B_n$ is refinement of $\mathcal A$.
>    Thus, $\mathcal B$ is open refinement of $\mathcal A$.
>
> Now, we have refinement $\mathcal B$ of $\mathcal A$  that is open covering of $X$ and $\sigma$-locally finite (or countably locally finite).
>
> Because $X$ is regular, we also have locally finite open refinement of $\mathcal A$ that covers $X$. And $X$ is paracompact.

Is here any problem in proof? I think this would be wrong, but I cannot find any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear, in your proof, why $\mathcal B_n$ would be locally-finite. Its restriction to $Y_n$ (that is, $\{B\cap Y_n:B\in\mathcal B_n\}$) is locally-finite in $Y_n$, but not necessarily in $X$.

You may take a specific example when the statement fails, and try to track exactly where your proof fails.

A standard example of a Tychonoff space that is not normal is the [Moore (or Niemytzki) plane, or tangent disk space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane). It is the $x$-axis together with the upper half-plane. If $H$ is the $x$-axis, then the topology induced on $H$ is discrete, hence $H$ is paracompact. If $K=\{(x,y):y>0\}$ is the upper half-plane then the topology induced on $K$ is the standard one, hence $K$ is also paracompact. Yet the Moore plane $\Gamma=H\cup K$ is not normal, hence it is not paracompact.

Comment: Oh now I got it. Thanks you a lot.